# Adding page breaks to pandoc latex template when converting markdown

Tags: page-breaking, templates, conversion, pandoc, markdown

Perhaps I'm missing something, but is there a way to either

(a) ensure that pandoc places pagebreaks before level 1 and level 2 headers in markdown (`#`,`##`), or

(b) hide `\newpage` from other markdown tools?

Is it possible to edit the template that pandoc uses for the conversion in order to do (a)?

Any ideas gratefully received.

:-)

Comment: You can easily tweak the style to get get pagebreaks before section. In ConTeXt, one can simply add `\setuphead[section,subsection][page=yes]`. The `titlesec` package in LaTeX should provide similar functionality.

Comment: Ok, pretend for a moment that I don't have a clue what ConTeXt is ;-)

Comment: So, what you're saying is `pandoc -s -w context doc.md -o doc.tex` then edit the `.tex` file to include your `\setuphead` line, and `context doc.tex` ?

Comment: Nope, that did something weird :-) Dropped me into a text editor (vim? emacs?) and complained bitterly.

Comment: ConTeXt is a TeX macro package (just like LaTeX is a TeX macro package). The method you described should work (I don't know what calling `context` will drop you into an editor). Ideally, you should modify the default ConTeXt template to create a custom template (see pandoc documentation) that has the above line included, so that you do not have to edit the file to add that line every time.

Answer (score 6):

`pandoc --chapters`, or `pandoc -V documentclass=memoir` or `pandoc -V documentclass=book` will tell pandoc to treat level 1 headers as chapters rather than sections. In both the book and memoir document classes, chapters are preceded by page breaks.

I'm not sure exactly what you need to set in your header to get page breaks before sections. Have you read the documentation for the memoir class? It includes a `\setbeforesectionskip{}` command that might a place to start.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that [LaTeX is not really intended for unattended typesetting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/162489/26348).

I concur with [Aditya](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/323/aditya) in that [ConTeXt](http://wiki.contextgarden.net) is better equipped in dealing with automated page breaks using a setup along the lines of:

```
\setuphead[section,subsection][page=yes, before={\placefloats\testpage[11]}]
```

However, in my personal experience, I have obtained even better, flawless results using [CSS paged media engines](https://www.print-css.rocks/); like for example [Prince XML](https://princexml.com/).

Read more about this [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/340365/26348).
The [PDFs on my personal web site](https://hamwaves.com/cl-ocfd/en/cl-ocfd.a4.pdf) are produced like this. [Inspect the `makefile`](https://hamwaves.com/cl-ocfd/en/cl-ocfd.a4.pdf) for the gory details.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a lua filter for this case see
[Pandoc Lua filter for page breaks](https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters/tree/master/pagebreak). Simply call:

```sh
$ pandoc --lua-filter pagebreak.lua -f markdown your.md
```